# Displaying Hindi font in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp

I have started learning JSP recently and i am NOT able to display hindi font "kruti dev" in my page. i browsed for the solutions and changed the page directives to

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" 
    import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
```

and the meta tags too

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
```

finally i have also changed the Eclipse settings:

> Window -> Preferences -> Web -> Jsp Files encoding to UTF-8

but still NO success.

here is the screenshot of mysql database and localhost:

[image]

The required font is installed on my system.
Do i need to configure anything else like including that font in my project resources or something like that..??

```
This is the code of the create table:

  -----+
| user_mst | CREATE TABLE `user_mst` (
  `UserCode` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `UserDispName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserDispName_Eng` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserCode`),
  KEY `DistCode` (`UserCode`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: What do you mean *not able to display*?

Comment: i am populating a Dropdown with list of users fetched from database, but it is NOT displaying them in HINDI but in raw english.

Comment: You are missing a double quote in charset=UTF-8"??

Comment: enclosing it in double quotes says undefined attribute charset..!

Comment: Can you show with an image what you're describing? How are they stored in and retrieved from your database?

Comment: @nitind : i've provided the screenshot for the same, please take a look at it.

Comment: I suspect DB encoding might be a problem. Can you show `show create table user_mst;` output.

Comment: @anubhava i have edited, please have a look.

Comment: Did you tried to set the table's default charset to utf8 ?

Comment: @Overnuts: No i didn't tried to do so, cause this will be a wrong practice to alter structure of a database. and also i have restrictions to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be other ways, but the database encoding is one of the reasons that you should check for. there is possibility that earlier in Spring 3.0., you had some functionality that allowed web pages to display hindi font.

Answer (score 1):

Ok as I suspected your char encoding in Database table looks suspicious here:

```
...
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

You need to make sure to use `utf8` in your database table:

```
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

That will mean modifying the table schema and reinserting the records again since existing data (using latin1 charset) can't be used to display hindi letters (charset=utf8)

**PS: Make sure you're using `utf8` all the way `inward` and `outward` while storing and fetching the data in order to correctly display it in browsers.**

Comment: sir, i would like to bring to your notice that the same database was used back in time along with Spring MVC framework, and i had seen it running in my system with Hindi Language. The same database has been used so there should be some solution apart from what you are suggesting.

Comment: I believe other than wrong encoding in database you have UTF8 everywhere else isn't it?

Comment: yes, i have purposefully used it everywhere to ensure from somewhere it should work, but sadly it doesn't. And i am still NOT sure i should change encoding in database, because, it had worked previously with same encoding.