# Getting junk value while sending hindi characher in request string

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, struts, multilingual

i am sending **`दर्शन`** as a request parameter value from javascript and while i am fetching in my struts action using **`requestMap.get(key)[0]`** then it gives me **`à¤¦à¤°à¥à¤¶à¤¨`** junk character?

here my action implements `ServletResponseAware` and i declare `requestMap` variable so it directly map request parameter value to `requestMap` object

Comment: Do you have a `requestMap` implementations?

Comment: yes Roman C i have that implementation
we hotfix this issue by sending data in post request

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding for HTTP protocol is not `utf8`. You need to handle it separately on your server side code.

Please refer the following link for more.

[Common problems with i18n and servlets/jsp-s](http://tagunov.tripod.com/i18n/i18n.html)

You need to add the following in your jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

[Displaying Hindi font in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410508/displaying-hindi-font-in-jsp)

Comment: thanks for reply
but i don't know how and where to change encoding to "UTF-16"
can u pls suggest me

Comment: according to that link in my jsp page i have to set content type
which i have set through this piece of line`<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-16" %>`

Comment: then you are displaying this value in jsp with the above line of code

Comment: still same issue persist after changing pageEncoding from `ISO-8859-1` to `UTF-16`

Comment: i added
`<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

` this line but problem persist